# AMFPHP call from server to client

Tags: actionscript-3, amfphp

Is it possible to call a client method from server using AMFPHP?

For example if there is a Flash chat app with PHP backend.
Everytime a new chat is logged from one of the clients, 
server would call update in all of the clients?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking it backwards. Server doesn't update the client on time or event basis. Client need to send request periodically, and server responds.

Comment: Why not, media servers use this approach typically.

Comment: Maybe there is atleast Remote Shared Object possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the server to broadcast events to your flash client, it would have to have a constant connection, which is not how amfphp works.  Your best bet would be to either set the client to periodically check amfphp for changes and act accordingly, or to look into a java-based server like Flash Media Server or SmartFoxServer.